# Sudden drop in water pressure at faucets closest to entry of main line

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, well, well-pump

Before I ask the question, I have to mention that I do have a water well.
The pressure is good at the farthest point, 100-200 feet from entry to house, the Guest bathroom.
The kitchen and master bath, at the farthest 50 feet, not good. The sink in the master bath will get good pressure, spitter and sputter then have pressure again. The shower in same bath is just dripping.
The kitchen sink is a steady flow, but is like you have the faucet barely open.
I have removed power from the pump and opened all the faucets and waited atleast 25-30 minutes. Left all faucets open and put power back to the pump, hoping to push the air through the pipes, but to no avail.
I was told that it could be that the water table is low. Just looking to see if it could be something else.
My question is, why am i getting good pressure at the farthest point from main line and not the closest?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please take the [tour] to get a better idea of how we work here. This is a Question & Answer site, and you haven't really asked a _question_. Please [edit] for some clarity (it's hard to follow your text description, maybe some formatting or even a little drawing - doesn't have to be to scale, just write the dimensions in) and to actually ask us a question so we can answer it.

Comment: That said, low water pressure at only some faucets leads me to believe that there are clogs/restrictions in the supply side plumbing. Check _all_ valves in the system to be sure they're fully open. Check strainers at taps to ensure they're not clogged. Do you have hard water coming from your well? If so, and if you don't have a water softener, there could be a fair bit of mineral build up in your supply side plumbing causing clogging.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply. I guess I got in a hurry and didn't ask my question the first time. But I think you answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

Low water pressure at only some faucets leads me to believe that there are clogs/restrictions in the supply side plumbing.

- Check all valves in the system to be sure they're fully open.
- Check strainers at taps to ensure they're not clogged.
- Do you have hard water coming from your well?

  - If so, and if you don't have a water softener, there could be a fair bit of mineral build up in your supply side plumbing causing clogging.

Comment: Ah, the random, drive by down voter who can't be bothered to say what the problem is. Life goes on...

Comment: I don't even know how to vote, let alone down vote, so wasn't me.

Comment: just found it. LOL

Comment: if I can bother you again, it is sputtering like air in the line. could that still be a clog?

Comment: That could be it, @RagingPaPa, however, we've had occasional issues like that over the last 2 years or so, and hadn't done any plumbing work on our house at all (nope, not even turning off valves) and we're on city water. I'd recommend asking about that specifically as a new question.

Comment: I see no reason for a DV. Upvoted.